# не могу отправить и загрузить файл

Tags: php, wordpress, файлы

я создал форму отправки письма с возможностью прикрепить файл

вот код

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
    echo $movefile['error'];
}

<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

после отправки получаю вот такую ошибку

*File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.*

я проверил настройки php.ini, загрузка файлов не отключена и размер не превышаю. через админ раздел загружаю фалы без проблем

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` в начале скрипта приема файла и смотрите, что там в массиве и откуда данные брать.

Comment: `enctype='multipart/form-data'` к форме отправки добавили?

Comment: о черт, я тупица :((( забыл добавить enctype='multipart/form-data' , все работает

Comment: Вначале говорит: `File is empty` - Файл пуст. Значит файл не дошёл до сервера или дошёл, но не полностью. Можно глянуть код ошибки: $_FILES['file']['error'] и узнать конкретнее, какое из этих недоразумений произошло.

Comment: @stashappy, код `php` нужно по условию запускать, а не напрямую лепить перед выводом `html`. Во всех примерах вижу такое написание.

Comment: новый вопрос. а как подцепить теперь этот загруженный файл что бы отправить его в письме?

Comment: @Visman, могу ли я глянуть на одно из подобных условий, чтобы лучше понять Вас?

Comment: @stashappy, в данном примере код `php` можно обернуть в условие `if (!empty($_FILES)) { php } html`.

Comment: А вот так нельзя: `if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) { HTML } elseif ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 1) { HTML } elseif ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 2) { HTML }`? http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: как мне после того как я загрузил файл с $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides ); прицепить его к  wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,$attachments);
?

Comment: @akasergej, чтобы отправить файл на e-mail в качестве вложения, нужно воспользоваться функцией `mail()` и "засунуть" в текст сообщения ваш файл. Есть подходящая статья: http://www.softtime.ru/scripts/mailattach.php

Comment: ну это я и так знал. не знал как указать именно этот файл. решил проблему.

Comment: @akasergej, файл отправляется уже не как файл, а как текстовая строка, полученная с помощью `file_get_contents($your_file)`.

Answer (score 1):

так как нигде не нашел полного кода отправки письма с wp_mail выкладываю свой рабочий код. может кому пригодится:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$fileupload = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

if ( $fileupload ) {
$attachments = $fileupload[ 'file' ]; }

$headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n"; 
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$headers.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 


wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,$attachments);
```

Comment: Пригодится, тому кто пользуется WordPress.